# Bootstrap v4 - responsive text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-4

How to use responsive text in bootstrap v4?
I tried:

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
  .resp-text {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
  .resp-text {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}
```

but not working.

Comment: Works fine when you use SASS https://www.codeply.com/go/948izzLfNz

Answer (score 2):

there could be multiple reasons

- ensure that you are using SASS with SASS Compiler if not then use normal media queries https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints
- if you are using SASS then ensure you have imported the correct mixins file to your core sass file.
- if you think everything is perfect then compile sass files separately and post screenshot of the error so we can get it perfectly.

Comment: I don't use SASS. I have this code in style.css and i have linked it in html page.